# Hover over image to show buttons and don't trigger when hovering over actual buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover

I'm trying to get buttons to appear when hovering over an image. The following works:

```
    jQuery('.show-image').mouseenter(function() {
 jQuery('.the-buttons').animate({
  opacity: 1
 }, 1500);
}).mouseout(function() {
 jQuery('.the-buttons').animate({
  opacity: 0
 }, 1500); 
});
```

However, when moving from the image to the button (which is over the image), the mouseout/mouseenter is triggered, so the buttons fade out then fade back in (the buttons have the same class as the image, otherwise they just stay faded out). How can I prevent this from triggering? I've also tried the above code using jQuery's hover; same results. Here's a detail of the image showing the button with opacity 1 (because I'm over the image):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/egeVq.png

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 8):

The simplest solution is to put the two in the same parent `div` and give the parent `div` the `show-image` class.

I like to use **[`.hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/)** to save a few key strokes. (alll hover does is implement **[`.mouseenter()`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/)** and **[`.mouseleave()`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/)**, but you don't have to type them out)

Additionally it's very imporant to fade `$(this).find(".the-buttons")` so that you only change the button in the hovered over `div` otherwise you would change all of the `.the-buttons` on the entire page! **[`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/)** just looks for descendants.

Finally, **[`.animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)** will work, but why not just use **[`.fadeIn()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/)** and **[`.fadeOut()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/)**?

JS:

```
jQuery(function() {                                              // <== Doc ready

    jQuery(".the-buttons").hide();                  // Initially hide all buttons

    jQuery('.show-image').hover(function() {
         jQuery(this).find('.the-buttons').fadeIn(1500);         // use .find() !
    }, function() {
        jQuery(this).find('.the-buttons').fadeOut(1500);         // use .find() !
    });
});
```

### [Try it out with this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jvX9u/)

HTML: - Something like this

```
<div class="show-image">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/egeVq.png" />
    <input class="the-buttons" type="button" value=" Click " />
</div>​
```

CSS: - Something like this. Yours will likely be different.

```
div {
    position: relative;
    float:left;
    margin:5px;}
div input {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0; }​
```

Answer (score 3):

Put the image and the button in the same div, then put the mouseover/mouseout events on the div. Than whether your mouse is over either the button or the image, it will still be over the div.

Also I am not sure if `mouseenter(...).mouseout(...)` will work. I always use `hover(..., ...)`

Comment: Yeah, I haven't seen "mouseenter" used much, but I have seen "mouseover" used a lot.

Comment: [ **`.hover()`** ](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) is simply a shortcut implementation of `.mouseenter()` and `.mouseleave()`