# Put images on top of another image using HTML?

Tags: html, css, image, browser, web

I was wondering how to have one image as a background, and put other button images on top of it in HTML?

Comment: I was wondering what I was going to cook for dinner..

Comment: Wow... what a bunch of downvoting snobs. Give the guy a break and answer his question.

Comment: can be done by using a z-index property of css!

Comment: most hotly contested question of the CENTURY.

Comment: @Homer6, the problem is his question is vague. Does he want the body to have a background image? A div with a background-image set? Two images overlaid? What..

Comment: he has a rep of 26... he just wants to make a webpage... he'll figure out the SO rules eventually... we don't have to jump down his throat the first one... and in case you have forgotten, you started somewhere too

Comment: @Homer6 and thats why questions like this will go un-answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13482341/video-not-playing-in-mpmovieplayer. Where's his code? Where's what he's attempted to fix it? I'm all for giving people instructions, but it gets annoying having to vaguely guess what people *actually* want, especially after 6 questions.

Comment: I'm pretty sure he wants a picture in front of another picture, and if some lives must be lost in the process then so be it.

Comment: @Alan please try to review this before you make more posts... thanks... http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hover over image to show buttons and don't trigger when hovering over actual buttons](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3946672/1037210).

Comment: Nah lion that one is more focused on animations and events. This one is just plain ol' markup.

Comment: Meno's Paradox. "How do you inquire into a thing when you don't know what it is?" I've had this problem hundreds of times. How's he supposed to know what to ask for if he doesn't know what to ask for? If he knew the terminology enough to ask a less vague question, chances are high he would have found the answer before posting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to place them in a container `div` and then position it relatively.

Something like this could do it:

```
<div style="position:relative; left:0; top:0;">
  <img src="x.png" style="position:relative; top:0; left:0;"/>
  <img src="y.png" style="position:absolute; top:30; left:70;"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked for the most part, but how would I do this if I use CSS to make a rollover button, here is my code for that: 
`<style type="text/css">
a.menurollover {
 display: block;
 width: 320px;
 height: 40px;
 background-image: url('menuButton1.jpg');
}

a.menurollover:hover {
 background-image: url('menuButton2.jpg');
}`

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can definitely do that... this article can give you a few tips on positioning images...

[Making an image position relative to the top of the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5250739/making-an-image-position-relative-to-the-top-of-the-page)